# Javascript function not recognized in CRM 2011 HTML Web resource

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011, webresource

Following up from my solved [previous issue][1], I'm having trouble building a simple HTML Web resource containing some basic javascript, page is rendered correctly but script doesn't seem to work properly.

My HTML resource is very basic:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="new_jquery_1.7.2.min" />
    <script type="text/javascript">    

        function buttonClick() { alert('Yo !'); }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="javascript: buttonClick();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Although the page shows up fine, clicking the button yields `The value of the property is null or undefined not a function object` error like the functions wasn't there, but I checked via F12 console that the code is rendered correctly.

I also tried invoking the web resource via the direct url, in the form of

```
http://mycrmserver/myorg/WebResources/new_myResource
```

But (as I expected) the behavior of the page was the same.

I checked Google, I surfed a couple of other SO questions *and* MSDN and all state this is the right way to do it, what's wrong with my code ?

Other (not sure if useful) details:

- If the F12 tool is open the error comes up as a `SCRIPT5007` javascript runtime error in the console. If it's not, I get the usual script error notify popup if I browse to the webresource direct url, or nothing happens at all if I try to open the resource inside the CRM.
- The CRM environment is updated to **Rollup 3** (updating it is *not* an option unfortunately)
- I'm using **IE 9** (Remember: Dynamics CRM can't be used in non-IE browsers yet)

---

**UPDATE**
Shorthand tags confuse the CRM.

Basically this syntax sometimes gets messed up:

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" />
```

But this works perfectly:

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>
```

Comment: Is the error that you're receiving coming up in the console, or is it loading an entirely new page with that error displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root cause is a missing `script` tag, despite the code you posted being correct.

CRM does some messing about with the HTML you post into the script editor window. What is rendered in the browser is this (note that the `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` tag is not closed in the same way as your pasted code):

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<SCRIPT src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx">
<script type="text/javascript" src="new_jquery_1.7.2.min" />
<script type="text/javascript">    

    function buttonClick() { alert('Yo !'); }

</SCRIPT>

<META charset=utf-8></HEAD>
<META charset=utf-8></HEAD>
<BODY><INPUT onclick=javascript:buttonClick(); value=Test type=button></BODY></HTML>
```

Resolution: 
Add full "close" tags to each opening script tag (rather than using "/>").

Comment: This feels odd *and* weird (and smells like a CRM bug) but the closing tags were in fact the solution.

Comment: Agreed! I've started to investigate the reason for this before now but didn't have the time. I think I might do some digging and finally update my blog ;)

Comment: I'll update the question to show how the (now working) code looks.